# Python: fastest strategy for remove a lot of keys from dict

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7, dictionary

As I know Python dictionary is a HashTable, which is resizing if size of table is more than 2/3 of max size of current table ([Objects\dictnotes.txt](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/dictnotes.txt)).

I need to remove a lot of dictionary items (several thousands), an example, one time an hour, based on simple criteria - if key <= guard_condition.

I know about dict comprehension for creating new dict, and resizing dict while iterating.

```
# dict comprehension
new_d = {key: value for key, value in d.iteritems() if key >= guard_condition }

# resize while iterating
for key in d:
    if key < guard_condition:
        del d[key]
```

Are there others approach for this purpose?
Which is faster?

Comment: Your two approaches don't produce the same output. The first will keep all keys that equal `guard_condition`, and the second will discard them.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to delete the items? Are you running low on memory? It would be faster to retain all items if possible and check new items against that condition.

Comment: "Several thousand keys, once per hour" does not sound much for a computer. How long does it actually take? How long do you need it to take? How big is the dictionary, are you removing most of it or keeping most of it? What kind of key value / guard condition test is it?

Comment: why don't you just try which is faster, and tell us. 
Also , how slow is the slowest?

Comment: Is this snippet actually a bottle neck of your application? You know: "Premature optimization..."

Comment: @Simon, it'll be processing based on data from external environment and, new items adds every minute and if dont delete obsolete data I'll be running low on memory :)

Comment: How about cProfiling this with a few thousand keys and identifying possible bottlenecks?

Comment: ok @viach I thought as much. How are you determining what to keep then? What does the threshold mean? You may be better using a LRU (least recently used) queue to determine what to delete, and deleting on the fly as new items are added, removing other items, rather than doing so en masse every so often. This will amortize the performance hit over time.

Comment: @Simon, thank you for LRU - I've never heared about this data structure yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's depend on your dictionary size and on how much elements you have to del: if you del less than 80% of your dictionary keys then "resize while iterating" is faster compared to "dict comprehension". If you del more than 80% of your dictionary keys then "dict comprehension" is faster. Try by yourself with this code

```
import cProfile, pstats, StringIO
pr = cProfile.Profile()
pr.enable()

guard_condition = int(raw_input("Enter guard_condition: "))

d = {item: item for item in xrange(10000000)};

new_d = {key: value for key, value in d.iteritems() if key >= guard_condition }

def del_iter(d, guard_condition):
    for key in d.keys():
        if key < guard_condition:
            del d[key]

del_iter(d, guard_condition)

pr.disable()
s = StringIO.StringIO()
sortby = 'cumulative'
ps = pstats.Stats(pr, stream=s).sort_stats(sortby)
ps.print_stats()
print s.getvalue()
```

For guard_condition = 7000000, output is

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
     1    2.794    2.794    2.794    2.794 {raw_input}
     1    1.263    1.263    1.263    1.263 dictDel1.py:7(<dictcomp>)
     1    1.030    1.030    1.030    1.030 dictDel1.py:9(<dictcomp>) <-- dict comprehension
     1    0.892    0.892    0.976    0.976 dictDel1.py:11(del_iter) <-- resize while iterating
     1    0.085    0.085    0.085    0.085 {method 'keys' of 'dict' objects}
     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'iteritems' of 'dict' objects}
     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

while with guard_condition = 8500000, output is

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
     1    3.316    3.316    3.316    3.316 {raw_input}
     1    1.247    1.247    1.247    1.247 dictDel1.py:7(<dictcomp>)
     1    0.937    0.937    1.052    1.052 dictDel1.py:11(del_iter) <-- resize while iterating
     1    0.787    0.787    0.787    0.787 dictDel1.py:9(<dictcomp>) <-- dict comprehension
     1    0.115    0.115    0.115    0.115 {method 'keys' of 'dict' objects}
     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'iteritems' of 'dict' objects}
     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've try with IPython and here's result:

```
In [140]: d = {item: item for item in xrange(10000)};

In [142]: guard_condition = 9000;

In [144]: %timeit new_d = {key: value for key, value in d.iteritems() if key >=
100 loops, best of 3: 2.54 ms per loop

In [140]: d = {item: item for item in xrange(10000)};

In [149]: def del_iter(d, guard_condition):
   .....:     for key in d.keys():
   .....:         if key < guard_condition:
   .....:             del d[key]
   .....:

In [150]: %timeit del_iter(d, guard_condition)
1000 loops, best of 3: 232 us per loop
```

The difference is about 100 loops * 2.54 ms = 254000 us VERSUS 1000 loops * 232 us = 232000 us, and its negligible for my situation.

I'll be use dict comprehension, because readabily counts and

As I see, the time for execution is a piece of cake and I agree to @Hyperboreus about premature optimization.

Comment: your timings shows that the dict comprehension is *10 times slower* then `del_iter()`. The dramatic difference might be due to `del_iter()` modifying `d` dictionary inplace (1 iteration to remove the keys, 999 iterations without removing anything).

Answer (score 0):

Further to my comment above - use an LRU (least recently used) or LFU (least frequently used) cache:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_algorithms

When new items come in, determine which to purge using an appropriate strategy. This amortizes the cost of deleting items over the lifetime of the app, rather than in occasional bursts where you selectively delete items.

I don't thin there is a faster way to delete from a dictionary using del[key] but there are much better ways to achieve what you are (I am guessing) trying to do. LRU and LFU are very popular and commonly used solutions to this.

Answer (score -1):

From pure performance point of view, while-loop is always faster than list comprehension whether you're programming in Ruby or Python. But since you're programming in Python, you probably want to go with list comprehension because you would not program in Python if speed is all of the essence.

Comment: Python's list comprehensions are implemented in C and therefore usually faster than `for` loops. But in this case the loops do something completely different -- the dict comprehension builds an entirely new dict, and the for loop removes elements from the old one. No blanket statements will help.

Comment: Agreed, comprehensions are quite fast.  And in this case, the issue is also whether it's faster to construct a new dictionary (with a dict comprehension) than to edit a existing one.

Comment: List comprehension is fast but viach's test just showed plain for loop is even faster. Or you can google around to see the performance difference.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich: [`dict` comprehension is 10 times slower in this case](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22669500/4279) but the examples do different things. Though even in those cases when a list comprehension and an explicit for-loop have the same effect; the explicit for-loop may be faster. I wouldn't say "always" but it is often faster in my experience.

Comment: *"you would not program in Python if speed is all of the essence"* seems unnecessary. In many ordinary programs, you need to speed up only 1% of the code to get time performance improvements. Often that 1% is already optimized in C code that is called from Python (database code, number-crunching code) or the code is I/O limited so the speed of your application code doesn't matter.